# Kubernetes Pod 00MKilled Issue

Tags: kubernetes

The scenario is we run some web sites based on an nginx image.
When we had our cluster setup with nodes of 2cores and 4GB RAM each.
The pods had the following configurations, cpu: 40m and memory: 100MiB.
Later, we upgraded our cluster with nodes of 4cores and 8GB RAM each.
But kept on getting 00MKilled in every pod.
So we increased memory on every pods to around 300MiB and then every thing seems to be working fine.

My question is why does this happen and how do I solve it.
P.S. if we revert back to each node being 2cores and 4GB RAM, the pods work just fine with decreased resources of 100MiB.

Any help would be highly appreciated.
Regards.

Comment: Can you please share a snippet with the manifest configuration for the said pod that was being OOM killed?

Comment: also I would argue that this question should be in https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

For each container in kubernetes you can configure resources for both cpu and memory, like following

```
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 100m
        memory: "200Mi"
      requests:
        cpu: 50m
        memory: "100Mi"
```

According to documentation

> When you specify the resource request for Containers in a Pod, the scheduler uses this information to decide which node to place the Pod on. When you specify a resource limit for a Container, the kubelet enforces those limits so that the running container is not allowed to use more of that resource than the limit you set.

So if you set `memory: 100MiB` on `resources:limits` and your container consume more than `100MiB` memory then you will get `out of memory (OOM)` error

For more details about request and limits on resources click [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits)

Comment: I think I was not clear enough for you.

My pods never gave an error of 00Mkilled in node configuration of 2core cpu 4gb ram, but error arises with a configuration of 4core cpu 8gb ram.

Nothing else is changed in the whole system